# How should we handle "Let me Google that for you"-type questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, close-reasons

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-can-i-find-dice-shops), which lay dormant since 2013 but was recently dug up and answered.

I feel like this question should have been closed, as the answer can totally be gotten by googling "dice/gaming shops in (wherever)".  So, I tried to flag it for closing, but none of the criteria fit.  I then scanned the relevant Help pages to see if such questions were off-topic here, and came up empty, and also checked here on Meta (cursorily searched for "Google") and came up with a related question that implied that while such questions were of poor quality, letting the user know that they could have Googled it was a sufficient answer.  In the end I just downvoted it for "lack of research" as per the tooltip and left it at that.

Was that the proper response, or *should* such questions be closed?  I feel like it's one thing if the user is looking for information that would be linked to via Google, like a gaming SRD, then the notion that the SE page on such a topic coming up first via Googling the topic is fine, but when the answer is literally a region-specific list of results gotten from Google itself, not so much.

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/314/on-banal-questions-answer-or-no-answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[We accept such questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions) (That's a link to the Meta.SE FAQ entry on this subject.)

In part, we do because we *are* the content that Google serves up, and if we can provide better content or a better synthesis of content than what a current Google search turns up, we will have magically improved future Google results.

In part, we do because we also [embrace the non-Googler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers). Google is a giant on the Internet, and so not everyone wants to put all their eggs in that one basket. Local, domain-specific knowledge-bases like RPG.se provide a way for knowledge to spread and be accessed without assuming everyone will/can/wants to rely on Google as their single choke-point to information.

As for [how to answer such questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8726):

> Either answer nothing, or give a correct answer.

There's no need to chastise the asker for not trying Google. (Note in particular that [the network has banned LMGTFY links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).) Of course, trivial questions might still earn downvotes for not showing any research effort, but warranting a downvote isn't the same thing as being closable. Your downvote-and-move-on response was exactly right.

Comment: Exactly.  If you think someone's putting so little effort into it that it is not respectful of your time to answer them, then don't answer them. That's fine and I do it myself on egregious examples. No need to begrudge someone else doing so though.

Comment: And if you still feel like you should do _something_, ask the OP in comments what they've tried searching so far.